# CodeIgniter $this->form_validation->set_message

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have made an email validation.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_email_check');

function email_check($str)
{
    if (stristr($str,'@uni-email-1.com') !== false) return true;
    if (stristr($str,'@uni-email-2.com') !== false) return true;
    if (stristr($str,'@uni-email-3.com') !== false) return true;
    $this->form_validation->set_message('email', 'Please provide an acceptable email address.');
    return FALSE;
}
```

After submitting my form, it says "Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name." is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('email_check', 'Please provide an acceptable email address.');
```

Comment: you saved me :) also, can you help me about this code. i've seen a loophole. yes you can enter your email according to the given email add. for example "test@uni-email-1.com" . the loophole in here, is you can add ".anytext" at the end of the given example. like "@uni-email-1.com.sjkla" .

Answer (score 4):

go to documentation for reference [HERE](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

To set your own custom message you can use the following function:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('rule', 'Error Message');
```

but you haven't named the rule correctly in your code it should be `email_check` instead of `email`

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('email_check', 'Please provide an acceptable email address.');
```

Comment: can you help me about this code. i've seen a loophole. yes you can enter your email according to the given email add. for example "test@uni-email-1.com" . the loophole in here, is you can add ".anytext" at the end of the given example. like "@uni-email-1.com.sjkla"